# Quando usar void Inject no Dagger

Tags: java, android, injeção-de-dependência

Dagger, alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Consegui fazer uns 3 projetos bem simples sempre tentando varias para ter problemas novos e aprender mais, mas uma parte eu estou meio que copiando pq não entendo, no Component tem alguns exemplos que mostram algo como:

```
void inject(MainActivity activity);
```

ou

```
void inject(BaseView mView); //Eu sei que o é BaseView e para que serve!!
```

Uma dúvida, para quer o `Inject`.
Minha dúvida é parte porque em outros exemplos não tem e muitas vezes tem também um:

```
Retrofit exposeRetrofit();
```

ou

```
Context exposeContext();
```

Li bem a documentação mas não conseguir enxergar como funciona isso. Quando uso `void inject(...);` e quando uso `Objeto exposeObjeto();`

Alguém sabe?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você coloca `void inject(MainActivity activity);` está definindo que a classe **MainActivity** vai poder utilizar as instâncias dos objetos que foram definidos no Módulo. Caso você precisasse utilizar o mesmo componente em um Fragment você também precisaria definir esse método lá `void inject(MeuFragment fragment);`.

Quando você define `Retrofit exposeRetrofit();` está expondo o objeto **Retrofit** que você definiu no Módulo, para que sua Activity ou Fragment possa utiliza-lo através do `@Inject Retrofit retrofit;`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Mas porque em alguns projetos mesmo quando esses provide são usados e no Component nao tem nenhum void inject(xxx); 

??